# Playing audio programmatically via NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

I've spent the whole day trying to get any of the `npm`packages related to playing audio from `nodejs` but couldn't get any to work.

Basically what I need is to play batch audios.

For example:

```
//files containing the name of the audios
var files = require('./list-of-audios-to-play.json')

var player = require('play-sound')(opts = {})

 var counter = 0;

  //every 5 seconds, play the referenced audio

  setInterval(function(){
    counter++;
    player.play(files[counter]+'.mp3', function(err){
      if (err) throw err
    })
  },5000)
```

Tried everything.

When I run the above code, I get this error:

```
INFORMATION: wasnt possible to locate files for the specified pattern(s)
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn play ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: We'd need to see the JSON file with the filenames in order to tell why it couldn't locate the file, and maybe the file tree on your system for the audio files as the error indicates that the filenames/patterns don't match your files.

Comment: looks like it can't locate the files.  I always have trouble with relative/absolute paths.  You can try console.log-ing `files[counter]` to see what path it is looking for.  Also you might want to use the nodejs [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) API (maybe `path.join`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It turned out I had to update npm.